# Facebook App Install ad campaign not allowing Branch.io deep link

Tags: facebook, deep-linking, facebook-ads-api, branch.io

I'm trying to create a Facebook App Install campaign. When I create the ad itself, it wont let me specify my Branch link as the deep link. I've used Branch links in other App Install campaigns, so not sure why it's failing now.

**Not Working:** http://fight.offtherecord.com/YUQk/RATIxDZQZw

**Working:** http://fight.offtherecord.com/YUQk/Frqjtf6gww

[image: Error when entering Branch link as deep link]

Comment: Perhaps just needs a re-scrape to recognize the app links. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 1):

Alex from Branch.io here: this is a known issue with Branch links in Facebook ads that comes up sometimes, and we're not even quite sure why or when. There are several workarounds you can try, detailed on [this page](https://dev.branch.io/features/facebook-ads/support/ios/#issues-reading-facebook-app-links).

To summarize, rescraping sometimes fixes the issue. This may also indicate that your Branch configuration is missing some required data. As a last resort, you can feed the Branch deep link ID directly into your ad to make sure deep linked behavior still works.

Comment: The link is dead